# Display deleted rows T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Help, please. Is there any other way to display deleted rows in SQL Server except for using trigger and deleted table or writing SELECT before DELETE with the same WHERE clause?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the output clause of the delete statement.

```
delete from yourtable 
output deleted.*
where ...
```

Comment: +1 amazing how many T-SQL programmers still don't know about the OUTPUT clause...

Comment: thanks, OUTPUT suits me perfectly! And I'm not SQL-programmer, I need SQL "by the way" for my own purpose =)

Comment: People like Mikael is offering us so many good complex solutions. Those solutions rarely gets more than 3 points. Sometimes those solutions includes code like this, combined with all kind of different gold. Now a simple oneliner is rewarding 7 points. Mikael you surely deserve the points, but mostly for your other answers :)

Comment: Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890473/order-by-row-number ?