# ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql, t-sql

UPD: thanks for all, topic closed, after sleeping I understand everything =)

I have a problem with understanding OVER clause and and ROW_NUMBER function. Simple table - name and mark. I want to calculate average mark for each name.

```
SELECT top 1 with ties name,  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) as number
FROM table 
ORDER BY AVG(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY name)
```

it will display something like this, and I understand why - that is what ROW_NUMBER() does

```
name|number
Pete 1
Pete 2
```

But if I write

```
SELECT top 1 with ties name,  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) as number
FROM table 
ORDER BY AVG(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY name), number
```

it will display

```
name|number
Pete 1
```

And this time I don't understand how ORDER BY works with ROW_NUMBER() function. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: perhaps it'll help if you add the AVG(mark) to the SELECT clause (and this results).  It may be obvious then.  (I bet the average is the same for Pete and John.)

Comment: source data is something like (Pete, 10), (Pete, 15), (Pete, 10), (John, 15), (John, 20). It doesn't matter

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107997/

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here: the windowing functions make no sense

Comment: Yes, it simply can be done without them, the clue is to understand how they work.

Comment: Note: OP's "it will display" section contains incorrect results.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 14):

You **can certainly order by ROW_NUMBER column** because the SELECT clause is evaluated before the ORDER BY clause.  You can ORDER BY any *column* or *column alias*.  This is why no error message was thrown (because it is valid).

```
SELECT name,  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) as number
FROM @table 
ORDER BY number
```

Evaluates to

```
name       number
---------- --------------------
John       1
pete       1
pete       2
John       2
pete       3
```

OP's second example of row_number is not correct.

```
SELECT AVG(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY name), name,  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) as number
FROM @table 
ORDER BY AVG(mark) OVER(PARTITION BY name), number
```

Returns as expected because AVG is the first sort column followed by number.

```
            name       number
----------- ---------- --------------------
11          pete       1
11          pete       2
11          pete       3
17          John       1
17          John       2
```

Change the query to **number DESC** and pete is still first however the row numbers are descending order.

```
            name       number
----------- ---------- --------------------
11          pete       3
11          pete       2
11          pete       1
17          John       2
17          John       1
```

**SQL Order of operations**

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

Comment: Yes, you are right in this. I was tired when I wrote this question, I entangled this query with another one. I've missed in a quary top 1 with ties

Answer (score 3):

You can't ORDER BY the ROW_NUMBER directly: I don't know why you didn't get an error on this case, but normally you would. Hence the use of derived tables or CTEs

```
SELECT
    name, number
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) as number,
       AVG(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS nameavg
    FROM table
    ) foo
ORDER BY
   nameavg, number
```

However, PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name is meaningless. Each partition has random order because the sort *is* the partition

I suspect you want something like this where ROW_NUMBER is based on AVG

```
SELECT
    name, number
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY nameavg) AS number
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
           name,
           AVG(mark) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS nameavg
        FROM table
        ) foo
    ) bar
ORDER BY
    number
```

Or more traditionally (but name is collapsed for the average)

```
SELECT
    name, number
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY nameavg) AS number
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
           name,
           AVG(mark) AS nameavg
        FROM
           table
        GROUP BY
           name
        ) foo
    ) bar
ORDER BY
    number
```

You can *maybe* collapse the derived foo and bar into one with

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY AVG(mark))
```

But *none* of this makes sense: I understand that your question is abstract about *how* it works bit it is unclear question. It would make more sense if you described what you want in plain English and with sample input and output

Comment: some good guy make the example of my query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107997/ . He just added few fields, but there query can be edited. There it also don't get any errors

Comment: Note that the statement "You can't ORDER BY the ROW_NUMBER directly" is not exactly correct.  You can order by the column alias without using a sub-query.