# SSIS Conditional Split

Tags: sorting, ssis, filtering, transformation, rank

I am importing a set of data into OLE DB SQL SERVER. I have two columns:

```
ID  CONDITION  CLIENT
1   A11111     G12345
1   X11111     G23456
2   A11111     G12345
2   A11111     G12345
3   A11111     G12345
3   A11111     G23456
4   X11111     G12345
```

I have to remove duplicates and upload table with transformation. If `condition` column duplicates have same values take that value in, if they differ take smaller one in. Same with the `client` column. I took this to temp table in SQL server, made ranking filtered using `rank==1` on both conditions using conditional split. Every thing worked well but for two records these rank on conditional column took to default but that record should flow through pipe line as client rank is `1`. Any suggestions to sort this issue please?

Comment: not sure I understand the problem, could you please post an example of the wrong and desired output?

Comment: For Example two records after ranking on both columns look like      ID  Condition Client  RankOnCondition RankOnClient                   1    A11111    G42345    1                2                         1    X11111    G23456     2               1 when i pass this record through conditional splits on using ranks this record goes to default because even if it pass through one rank conditional split it goes to default from other split. Any possible solutions for this to take the records to database

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to remove duplicates would be to use either a GROUP BY or DISTINCT clause in your select statement.

Alternatively, if you are looking for the latest values, a row_number() statement grouped by Id, ordered by UpdateDate? descending.  The result of the row_number per id would enable you to select only those rows that have a row_number of 1 per id.  [For a similar Row_Number example have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890473/order-by-row-number)

Answer (score 0):

your first conditional should have 2 outputs: the positive, when rank==1,should output to a UNION ALL transformation, and the default output to the second conditional.
the second conditional should also output rank==1 to the UNION ALL transformation.

The output of the UNION ALL will then have any row that passed one OR the other conditional.